# JavaScript: check if a giving string contains only letters or digits

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, I wanna check if a giving string contains only letters or digits and not a special characters:

I find this code which checks if a string contains only letters:

```
    boolean onlyLetters(String str) {
      return str.match("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    }
```

but my string can contain digits too. can you help me?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add 0-9 also to your regex

```
 boolean onlyLetters(String str) {
   return str.match("^[A-Za-z]+$");
 }
 
 boolean onlyDigits(String str) {
   return str.match("^[0-9]+$");
 }

 boolean isAlphanumeric(String str) {
   return str.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$");
 }
```

Comment: str.match instead of str.matches would be better

Comment: This also return not null value for `onlyLetters("ser[]ver")`

Comment: @Dandelion Fixed. The previous answer was plain wrong

Answer (score 8):

Using regexp, you can add `0-9` to say any digit between 0 and 9:

```
boolean onlyLettersAndDigits(String str) {
      return str.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    }
```

Comment: There isn't string.matches in javascript